regarding Solution for date issue
insert into payment(customer_id,amount,mode,payment_date)
values
(1,60,'Cash',2020-09-24),
(10,70,'Mobile payment',28-02-2021),
(11,'80,Cash',01-03-2021),
(2,500,'Credit Card',27-04-2020),
(8,100,'Cash',26-01-2021);

ERROR:  column "payment_date" is of type date but expression is of type integer
LINE 4:  (1,60,'Cash',2020-24-09),
Please help me resolve this issue as I am not getting what to do.
its been correct into a Youtube video but in mine its going wrong.

2020 minus 24 minus 9. That’s not a date, that’s a calculation

PostgreSQL expects date to be in the format YYYY-MM-DD and to be enclosed in single quotes.
INSERT INTO payment (customer_id, amount, mode, payment_date)
VALUES
    (1, 60, 'Cash', '2020-09-24'),
    (10, 70, 'Mobile payment', '2021-02-28'),
    (11, 80, 'Cash', '2021-03-01'),
    (2, 500, 'Credit Card', '2020-04-27'),
    (8, 100, 'Cash', '2021-01-26');


Just like almost any database, this is not limited to just PostgreSQL
